# What is OSNR in Fiber Optics?

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, snr

I have seen that the SNR is measured for optical fibers "OSNR". What is the difference? Is there any equivalent?

Comment: Have you read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio#Optical_SNR ?